# iOS filter an array with an array

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist, nspredicate

I have an array of strings that I want to use as the filter for another array of dictionaries that is created from a plist. For example, if I had a plist of dictionaries that looked like so:

```
Key:      Value:
car1      audi
car2      bmw
car3      bmw
car4      audi
car5      jaguar
```

and my array of strings was "audi, jaguar". How would I code it so that I can create a new array that would return "car1, car4, car5"? Hope this makes sense. Or better yet, how can I walk down this dictionary and filter it based on a value and then create a new array of dictionaries to use.

Code:

```
-(void)plotStationAnnotations {

desiredDepartments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

BOOL tvfrSwitchStatus = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"tvfrSwitchStatus"];
BOOL hfdSwitchStatus =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hfdSwitchStatus"];

if (tvfrSwitchStatus) {
    NSString *tvfr = @"TVF&R";
    [desiredDepartments addObject:tvfr];
}
if (hfdSwitchStatus) {
    NSString *hfd = @"HFD";
    [desiredDepartments addObject:hfd];
}

NSLog(@"Array 1 = %@", desiredDepartments);

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stationAnnotations" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *anns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableArray *newDictionaryArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in anns) {
    for (NSString *string in desiredDepartments) {
        if ([dictionary allKeysForObject:string]) {
            [newDictionaryArray addObject:dictionary];
            break;
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"Array = %@", keyMutableArray);

for (int i = 0; i < [keyMutableArray count]; i++) {

    float realLatitude = [[[keyMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
    float realLongitude = [[[keyMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];

    StationAnnotations *myAnnotation = [[StationAnnotations alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;
    myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
    myAnnotation.title = [[keyMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"station"];
    myAnnotation.subtitle = [[keyMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"department"];
    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like

```
NSArray *array1;
if([array1 containsObject : someValue])
```

can help. someValue can be your values you want to check if they exist in array1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to filter by keys:

```
NSArray *keysToLookFor = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"car1", @"car4", @"car5", nil];
NSArray *foundObjects = [dictionary objectsForKeys:keysToLookFor notFoundMarker:nil];
```

Or something like this to filter by values:

```
NSString *valueToLookFor = @"Audi";
NSArray *keyArray = [dictionary allKeysForObject:valueToLookFor];

// To filter by multiple values
NSArray *valuesToFilterBy = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bmw", @"Audi", nil];
NSMutableArray *keyMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *string in valuesToFilterBy) {
    [keyMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[dictionary allKeysForObject:string]];
}
```

Updated answer for dictionaries in arrays:

```
NSArray *dictionaryArray; // The array of dictionaries that you have
NSMutableArray *newDictionaryArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *valuesToFilterBy = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bmw", @"Audi", nil];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dictionaryArray) {
    for (NSString *string in valuesToFilterBy) {
        if ([dictionary allKeysForObject:string]) {
            [newDictionaryArray addObject:dictionary];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you have 'dictionary'? I have an array of dictionaries... so how  would I do it that way?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean when you say that you have an array of dictionaries, your plist should be just one dictionary with the keys and values that you provided above in that one dictionary.  Is each value/key that you provided above in separate dictionaries?  If so, you should keep them in one dictionary, not in an array of dictionaries.

Comment: I have an array of about 30 dictionaries. Each dictionary has 4 elements in it.

Comment: Have update answer to account for dictionaries in an array, I wasn't sure if you wanted to keep a filtered array of the dictionaries or a filtered array of keys for the specified values you filter with but the code can be easily altered to keep a filtered array of dictionaries.

Comment: Basically, in that plist, there a more dictionaries with different values for department. I have an array of strings, for example @"TVF&R, HFD, CFD", and I want to create a new array of dictionaries from the original with those who's department equal to one of the objects in the string array.

Comment: I have updated the answer one more time, please don't forget to accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: I added my code up top so you can see what I am doing. I am getting a *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11c7e200'

Comment: the keyMutableArray is just an array of strings but if you look at the end of my updated answer, i have turned it into an array of dictionaries so it would have the selector objectForKey, look for newDictionaryArray in the updated answer.

Comment: try casting it like this [((NSString *)[((NSDictionary *)[keyMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]) objectForKey:@"latitude"]) floatValue]; I am going to bed now, its like 2 am but ill check in the morning to see if you had any more problems.  good luck

Comment: Alright, I messed up a little on my end. Fixed the error, but the new dictionary array has everything old one does. It is not being filtered according to the desiredDepartments array, but thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: I think that the desiredDepartments array is holding both tv&r and hfd at the end of those if statements so you are filtering by the two values that every dictionary holds and thus get every dictionary back.  To test this, comment out the tv&r if statement and run the code.

Comment: That piece of code works fine. I can have desiredDepartments only contain Hfd and I still get ever dictionary back. Also for your information, there a total of 7 different values that are for the key department. Tvfr and HFD are two of them. I haven't added the other if statements to contain the other 5 possible choices.

Comment: Also, is there a way to only check one key in every dictionary, or does it have to stay like it is now, where it checks every key in every dictionary? It would be nice to only check the department key in each dictionary.